# How to Create a Tertiary Feature Branch With a Correct Git Diff

Tags: git, github, branch, branching-and-merging, git-diff

If I want to create a new feature branch off master, I can do:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b myFirstFeature
```

But suppose I now have that branch up in a PR that is waiting to be merged, and I want to work on something else that depends on the changes that are in that branch. In that case I might create a tertiary branch by doing:

```
$ git checkout myFirstFeature
$ git checkout -b mySecondFeature
```

So now I've set `myFirstFeature` as upstream of `mySecondFeature` and I have access to all the changes there and can start building on them, which is what I wanted. Nice!

*However*, the issue is that when I put up a PR for `mySecondFeature`, Git includes all the changes from `myFirstBranch` in the diff for `mySecondFeature`, rather than just what I actually committed to `mySecondFeature`.

It even includes the changes that resulted from any time I pulled master, ie any other PRs that were merged during the time `myFirstFeature` has existed.

So now `mySecondFeature` has a diff on GitHub of like 200 files, even though I personally only edited 3 or 4 on that branch.

How can I achieve my goal of creating a new tertiary feature branch off of an existing un-merged feature branch without totally borking my git diff?

thanks!

Comment: Watch out for the word *upstream*, which has a technical definition in Git (that this doesn't meet) and another common usage in Git (that this also doesn't meet) and also means just what you are using it to mean. So it means three different things. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

`git checkout master`

`git checkout -b new_branch` (create a new branch)

`git merge --squash old_branch` (merge in the dependant feature branch)

if you did this wrong the first time and now have work on another branch you want to pull in to `new-branch`, do:

`git cherry-pick <oldest_commit>^..<newest_commit>`

Answer (score 0):

Start with a PR which asks to merge `mySecondFeature` to `myFirstFeature`.

Update the target branch of that PR to `master` after `myFirstFeature` has been merged to `master`.